# Why does the UNIX system need so many [0-byte] drives at /dev/*

Tags: devices

So I recently asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176281/how-to-inspect-the-contents-of-dev-sdt), which lead me to run this command:

`$ du -sk /dev/*`

Which outputs about 353 different entries that look like this:

```
0   /dev/sdt
0   /dev/stderr
0   /dev/stdin
0   /dev/stdout
0   /dev/systrace
0   /dev/tty
0   /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
0   /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
0   /dev/ttyp0
0   /dev/ttyp1
```

#### Can someone please elaborate on what these directories are? And why are they all zero bytes?

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate question. The duplicate question simply explains the general nature of the device nodes at /dev/* but the accepted answer on the post you claim is a duplicate doesn't seem to mention the zero-byte file size, and my question is specifically asking about file size.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're [device nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file):

> In Unix-like operating systems, a device file or special file is an
>   interface for a device driver that appears in a file system as if it
>   were an ordinary file. [...] They allow software to interact with a device
>   driver using standard input/output system calls, which simplifies many
>   tasks and unifies user-space I/O mechanisms.

In other words, they're not normal files, although they may be organized into regular directories.  Historically, these were actual nodes created on disk that contained a smidge of information for the kernel.  On contemporary linux systems, this has been replaced with a special in-memory filesystem, **devtmpfs**, much like `/proc` is an in-memory procfs and `/sys` an in-memory sysfs.  That's why they are listed as having 0 bytes -- they are direct interfaces with kernel.

As to what they all are, there is a section about "Naming Conventions" in that wikipedia article, although this is not binding or universal (they may be renamed from userspace, which e.g., RedHat/Fedora derived udev installations will do).  You can get another couple of clues from the major/minor number, shown in two columns left of the date with `ls -l` (where "size" would be).  Those numbers correspond to entries in `/sys/dev/block` or `/sys/dev/char`.

Keep in mind most of these devices are *virtual* and may have little or nothing to do with any particular part of the hardware.  For example, `tty` devices are the virtual terminals you can navigate with ctrl-alt-F[N]; `pt` devices (there's a directory for them) are pseudo-terminals used in GUI emulators. There are various other more esoteric things such as shared memory segments (under `shm` -- these have actual sizes).  Again, the purpose is just to allow for a standardized interface to the kernel; the concept of "device" is very loose.

Comment: Most contemporary Linux distributions _don't_ actually use devfs, but an ordinary ramdisk (tmpfs) filesystem whose content is managed by the **udev** system running outside the kernel.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I hadn't noticed the distinction between `devfs` and `devtmpfs` (corrected).  `udev` (which is a userspace entity) may manage aspects of this but AFAICT the preliminary set-up is still by the kernel, and using a dev node is still a kernel interface (i.e., udev is not a gatekeeper that way).

Comment: x @goldilocks: Hm, turns out I had a too simplistic model of how udev works -- `mount` on my box says that `/dev` is an ordinary `tmpfs` with no magical properties, but `/proc/mounts` knows it as `devtmpfs`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's all magical ;)