# Using diff to compare the output of two commands

Tags: diff, stdout, dash

How does one go about using `diff` to compare the output of two commands?

I know how to use it to compare the contents of a file `filename1` with the output of a command `cmd2`:

```
cmd | diff filename -
```

How do I make it so that I can have another command, say `cmd1` in place of `filename`?

I'm using dash, which doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: with process substitution `diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310500/72456

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [How to emulate Process Substitution in Dash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310500/86440) (thanks [αғsнιη](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72456/%CE%B1%D2%93s%D0%BD%CE%B9%CE%B7)!), adjusted for `dash`:

```
( cmd1 | ( cmd2 | ( diff /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 ) 4<&0 ) 3<&0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

easy :-)

```
$ cat file1 | diff /dev/stdin /dev/stderr 2<< EOT
> `cat file2`
> EOT
2c2
< 2
---
> 4
```