# How to compare two different files line by line in unix?

Tags: text-processing, awk, diff

File1:

```
123
234
345
456
```

File2:

```
123
234
343
758
```

Expected output:
File3:

```
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
```

so the code should compare two files and print 'TRUE' if it matches otherwise it should print 'FALSE' in the new file. Could anyone please provide the solution for this?

Comment: What happens if the two files are of unequal length? What part of the solution of this issue are you having problems with?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `diff`.

Comment: Other useful command in these situations is `comm`. It makes it easy to list lines that both files have in common or are unique to one or the other.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta The thing with `comm` is that it requires sorted input. Apart from the fact that the example in the question _does_ have sorted input, the question never asserts that this is the actual data that is being used and never says anything about the ordering of the data.

Comment: αғsнιη's `nl` trick is useful with `comm` for imposing sorted-ness on the files.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, that's why I posted it as a comment. It's useful when you want to compare stuff like data files where the sorting order probably does not matter. For code/texts it's not useful.

Answer (score 56):

Use `diff` command as following, in `bash` or any other shell that supports `<(...)` [process substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) or [you can emulate it as shown here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512510/72456):

```
diff --new-line-format='FALSE'$'\n' \
     --old-line-format='' \
     --unchanged-line-format='TRUE'$'\n' \
<(nl file1) <(nl file2)
```

Output would be:

```
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
```

`--new-line-format='FALSE'$'\n'`, print *`FALSE`* if lines were differ and with `--old-line-format=''` we disable output if line was differ for file1 which is known as *old* file to diff command (We could swap these as well, meaning that one of them should print `FALSE` another should be disabled.)

`--unchanged-line-format='TRUE'$'\n'`, print *`TRUE`* if lines were same. the `$'\n'` C-style escaping syntax is used to printing a new line after each line output.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming the files contain no tab-characters:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ print ($1 == $2 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") }'
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
```

This uses `paste` to create two tab-delimited columns, with the contents of the two files in either column.  The `awk` command compares the two columns on each line and prints `TRUE` if the columns are the same and otherwise prints `FALSE`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming both files have the same number of lines:

```
awk '{getline f2 < "file2"; print f2 == $0 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"}' file1
```

That's doing a numerical comparison if the strings to compare are numbers and lexical otherwise. For instance, `100` and `1.0e2` would be considered identical. Change to `f2"" == $0` to force a lexical comparison in any case.

Depending on the `awk` implementation, lexical comparison will be done as if by using `memcmp()` (byte-to-byte comparison) or as if by using `strcoll()` (whether the two strings sort the same in the locale's collation order). That can make a difference in some locales where the order is not properly defined for some characters, not on all decimal digit input like in your sample.

Answer (score 7):

#### Python 3

```
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        print(line1 == line2)
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
False
```

If you need `TRUE` and `FALSE` in uppercase, replace the print line with one of these:

```
print(str(line1 == line2).upper())
print('TRUE' if line1 == line2 else 'FALSE')
```

Comment: In Python 2, do an `import itertools` first, and then use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`. Otherwise it will read both files to memory, possibly using too much memory.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash`, reading from each file in a `while` loop, comparing the read lines and printing `TRUE` or `FALSE` appropriately:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 line1; IFS= read -r -u4 line2; do
    [[ $line1 == $line2 ]] && echo TRUE || echo FALSE
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

The two calls to `read` reads from file descriptor 3 and 4 respectively.  The files are redirected to these with two input redirections into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tried with awk command and it worked fine


awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{if ($1 in a){print "TRUE"} else{print "False"}}' file1 file2
```

output

```
TRUE
TRUE
False
False
```